# PHP product comparison script calculator

Tags: php

I had a fairly simple question (i think) but I could not find a clear answer on Google nor Stackoverflow. I am looking for a script for a simple PHP calculator and I found multiple, however I want the script to calculate multiple formulas and display answers to all these calculated formulas (sorry for my unclear explaination, english is not my mative language), I will explain in more detail below with a practical example.

Visitor of the website needs to supply 3 values, Value one and value two, these can be numbers between 1 and 20000 and a third value which is a dropdown of either 1 or 2 Then the script needs to make 8 calculations with these values + preset values.

1. Value 1 * Value 2 * 0,0275 + 400/ Value 3 = output one
2. Value 1 * Value 2 * 0,0275 + 400/ Value 3 / Value 2 = output two
3. Value 2 * 0,055 + 400/ Value 3 = output three
4. Value 2 * 0,055 + 400/ Value 3 / Value 1 = output four
5. Etc.

However I cannot find out how I should adjust the script to do this.

```
<?php 
$page = $_GET['page']; 

class calc { 
 var $number1; 
 var $number2;
 Var $number3; 

      function oper($value1,$value2,$value3) 
      { 
        $result1 =$value1 x value2 x 0,0275 + 400 ÷ value3;
           Echo(“Outcome one is $result1<br><br>”);
           Echo(“$value1 x value2 x 0,0275 + 400 ÷ value3 =$result1”);
        $result2 =$value1 x value2 x 0,0275 + 400 ÷ value3 ÷ value 2;
           Echo(“Outcome one is $result2<br><br>”);
           Echo(“$value1 x value2 x 0,0275 + 400 ÷ value3 ÷ value2 =$result2”);
                exit; 
       } 
} 
$calc = new calc(); 
?> 
<TITLE>Test calculator</TITLE> 
<form name="calc" action="?page=calc" method="POST"> 
Value 1: <input type=text name=value1><br> 
Value 2: <input type=text name=value2><br>
Value 3: <select option=”value 3”>
<option value=”1”>1</option>
<option value=”2”>2</option></select>
Value 2: <input type=text name=value3><br>
<br> 
<input type=submit value="Calculate"> 
</form> 
<?php 
if($page == "calc"){ 
$value1 = $_POST['value1']; 
$value2 = $_POST['value2']; 
$value3 = $_POST['value2'];
$oper = $_GET['oper']; 
 if(!$value1){ 
      echo("You must enter number 1!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
 if(!$value2){ 
      echo("You must enter number 2!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
 if(!$value3){ 
      echo("You must enter number 2!"); 
      exit; 
 }
 if(!eregi("[0-9]", $number1)){ 
      echo("Value 1 MUST be numbers!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
 if(!eregi("[0-9]", $number2)){ 
      echo("Value 2 MUST be numbers!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
} 
?>`
```

Does anyone have any solution?

**Thanks for all your quick replies**, I adjusted the code, now it does not provide errors anymore, however it still does not show the answers to the formula

```
class calc {
function calculate($value1,$value2,$value3)
{
    $result1 = $value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400 / $value3;
    echo("Outcome one is $result1<br><br>");

    $result2 = $value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400 / $value3 / $value2;
    echo("Outcome two is $result2<br><br>");

    exit;
}
}
$calc = new calc(); 
?> 
<TITLE>Test calculator</TITLE> 
<form name="calc" action="?page=calc" method="POST"> 
Value 1: <input type=text name=value1><br> 
Value 2: <input type=text name=value2><br>
Value 3: <input type=text name=value3><br>
Method: <input type=radio name=calculate value="calculate">Test</input><br>
<br> 
<input type=submit value="Calculate"> 
</form> 
<?php 
if($page == "calc"){ 
$value1 = $_POST['value1']; 
$value2 = $_POST['value2']; 
$value3 = $_POST['value3'];
$calculate = $_POST['calculate']; 
 if(!$value1){ 
      echo("You must enter number 1!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
 if(!$value2){ 
      echo("You must enter number 2!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
 if(!$value3){ 
      echo("You must enter number 3!"); 
      exit; 
 } 
 if(!$oper){
      echo("Must be selected!");
      exit;
 } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it sounds a bit easy, but could you try to change the "x" to "*" and the "÷" to "/" in $result1 and $result2?

Comment: for one thing, you have a bunch of curly quotes that are choking your code `“ ”` if that's your actual code. Which should all be `"`. Error reporting should be throwing something to you about those.

Comment: then your `<select>`, that needs a name attribute, not a value. And `eregi()` that's deprecated. Where did you get this code from anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the problem is that you never called the function `calculate()`. When you don't call a function, you also won't get the output you expect.

I changed a few things in your script.

1. You never checked if the `$_POST` values exists in line 26. There are a lot of ways to check if the input is submitted, I used the `isset()` function. If the input is submitted, the value of `$value` will be the value of the input, when it is not submitted, the input will be empty.
2. Instead of using `!$value`, it is better to check if the input exists (line 26) and if it is not empty. We use `empty()` for that.
3. I couldn't find `$oper`. I suppose you mean `$calculate`.
4. Instead of using `exit()`, you better use `elseif()`. That also makes it easier to use `else()` and call your function
5. You forget to call the function `calculate`.
6. Please use valid HTML formatting.

So, after changing these things, you will get this output:

```
<?php
class calc {
    function calculate($value1,$value2,$value3){
        $result1 = $value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400 / $value3;
        echo("Outcome one is $result1<br><br>");

        $result2 = $value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400 / $value3 / $value2;
        echo("Outcome two is $result2<br><br>");

        exit;
    }
}
$calc = new calc(); 
?> 
<TITLE>Test calculator</TITLE> 
<form name="calc" action="?page=calc" method="POST"> 
Value 1: <input type="text" name="value1"><br> 
Value 2: <input type="text" name="value2"><br>
Value 3: <input type="text" name="value3"><br>
Method: <input type="radio" name="calculate" value="calculate">Test</input><br>
<br> 
<input type=submit value="Calculate"> 
</form> 
<?php 
if($_GET['page'] == "calc"){
    $value1 = isset($_POST['value1']) ? $_POST['value1'] : '';
    $value2 = isset($_POST['value2']) ? $_POST['value2'] : '';
    $value3 = isset($_POST['value3']) ? $_POST['value3'] : '';
    $calculate = isset($_POST['calculate']) ? $_POST['calculate'] : '';
    if(empty($value1)){
        echo("You must enter number 1!"); 
    } elseif(empty($value2)){ 
        echo("You must enter number 2!");
    } elseif(empty($value3)){ 
        echo("You must enter number 3!"); 
    } elseif(empty($calculate)){
        echo("Must be selected!");
    } else{
        // If all inputboxes are not empty and the checkbox is ticked -> Calculate
        $calc->calculate($value1,$value2,$value3);
    }
} 
?>
```

I tested it and it works. Be sure that you know why I made some changes for the future.

If you still got any questions, feel free to comment below.

Comment: Dear Frank, thank you very much for your help. I have upvoted you but not enough points to affect the score. Script works like fine :)
I have one question, maybe it’s too complicated but I would like to have the script use a different calculation method regarding the input. For example if value1 * value2 are above 4000 it should calculate value1 * value 2 * 0,01 instead of 0,0275. I found a short script not quite sure how I should implement it
    $var1 = 2020;
    if ( $var1 >= 2000 && $var1 <= 4000) {
    echo 'true';
    }
    else echo 'false';
Regardless, thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi Nova, 

If the answer is the solution for your problem you can "accept it as an answer". Making an answer accepted helps other people to find answers

According to your question:
You can add/change this in `calculate()`: (above `$result1`):
if(($value1 * $value2) > 4000){
$multiplier = 0.01;
} else{
$multiplier = 0.0275;
}

And you have to change "0.0275" to `$multiplier` in `$result1` and `$result2`.

What it does:
It defines the multiplier, it is 0.01 when `$value1 * $value2` is above 4000, otherwise it is 0.0275.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Youre help is awesome, voted already for best answer. One last question, if I want to have multiple multipliers e.g. >4000 = multiplier 0.01, >8000 = multiplier 0.005 how do I do that? I tried and or and else, but none seem to work.

Comment: You can use `elseif()`. if(($value1 * $value2) > 8000){ $multiplier = 0.005; } elseif(($value1 * $value2) > 4000){ $multiplier = 0.01; } else{ $multiplier = 0.0275; }

Be sure to start with the 8000 option, because 8000 is also higher than 4000.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
class calc {
    function oper($value1,$value2,$value3)
    {
        $result1 = $value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400 / $value3;
        echo("Outcome one is $result1<br><br>");

        $result2 = $value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400 / $value3 / $value2;
        echo("Outcome two is $result2<br><br>");

        exit;
    }
}
$calc = new calc();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are not using proper PHP coding at all !**

For answer, try change all calculations like :

```
$v1 = ($value1 * $value2 * 0.0275 + 400) / $value3;
```